# CSS3 - hover display different element

Tags: css, hover

is it possible to have purely css (not javascript) this:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>

<div id="x" style="display:none;">c</div>
```

Display the `<div>` when I hover a `<li>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `li` elements are in that `ul`, so `#x` is no longer reachable from `li:hover`. So if you must have the hover effect only on the `li` elements, you'll need JavaScript.

If not, you could do this instead:

```
/* Or ul:hover ~ #x if there are any other elements between them */
ul:hover + #x {
    display: block;
}
```

But the cursor can be anywhere on the `ul` itself for `#x` to show up, rather than being directly on any `li`, which isn't quite what you want unless your `li`s take up the entire `ul` area.

Comment: tx @BoltClock what if you want to make #x show up on the first li only?

Answer (score 1):

Almost but li are not a [Adjacent sibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) for div#x They would be if you placed the div inside the ul element.

```
<style>
ul:hover + #x {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>

<div id="x">c</div>
```

Comment: Except you can't have `div`s directly inside `ul`s.

Comment: UL is a block element http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html you can also make the li into block elements and then have blocks as children. li{display:block} http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/ you should not place blocks in display:inline elements but I do not believe it actually fails.

Comment: It doesn't matter that `ul` and `div` are block elements. A `ul` can **only** have `li` as children and nothing else to validate.

Comment: Which validator? http://validator.nu/ http://validator.w3.org seem to both validate CSS menus using div (AKA mega menus) without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go with JavaScript as the "div" is outside the list.